# How to compare means (µ1 + µ2 + µ3)/3 = (µ3 + µ4)/2 in SAS: Use 'ESTIMATE' or 'CONTRAST'?

Tags: sas, glm

I am working with a dataset of 5 techniques of assembling parts, with random samples of workers taken from each technique for evaluation on how long it takes workers to complete the task. I wish to compare means with a `t-test`, but am struggling to get the correct code, as I am very new to SAS.

The dataset can be found with the following code:

```
data Ex1;
input technique time @@;
lines;
1 45.6
1 41
1 46.4
1 50.7
1 47.9
1 44.6
2 41
2 49.1
2 49.2
2 54.8
2 45
3 51.7
3 60.1
3 52.6
3 58.6
3 59.8
3 52.6
3 53.8
4 67.5
4 57.7
4 58.2
4 60.6
4 57.3
4 58.3
4 54.8
5 57.1
5 69.6
5 62.7
;
run;
```

I wish to use `PROC GLM` to test the null hypothesis of (µ1 + µ2 + µ3)/3 = (µ3 + µ4)/2, compared to the alternative that these means are not equal. I have the following code for this operation, but I am getting errors when I run it:

```
proc glm data=Ex1;
class technique;
model time=technique/NOINT SOLUTION E;

CONTRAST 'M1+M2+M3=M3+M4' technique 1 1 1 0 0/DIVISOR=3, technique 0 0 1 1 0/DIVISOR=3;
run;
```

The following output error is produced:

```
1          OPTIONS NONOTES NOSTIMER NOSOURCE NOSYNTAXCHECK;
 72         
 73         proc glm data=Ex1;
 74         class technique;
 75         model time=technique/NOINT SOLUTION E;
 76         
 77         CONTRAST 'M1+M2+M3=M3+M4' technique 1 1 1 0 0/DIVISOR=3, technique 0 0 1 1 0/DIVISOR=3;
                                                          _______
                                                          22
                                                          76
 NOTE: The previous statement has been deleted.
 ERROR 22-322: Syntax error, expecting one of the following: ;, E, EST, ETYPE, SINGULAR.  
 ERROR 76-322: Syntax error, statement will be ignored.
 78         run;
 
 NOTE: Due to the presence of CLASS variables, an intercept is implicitly fitted.  R-Square has been corrected for the mean.
 79         
 80         OPTIONS NONOTES NOSTIMER NOSOURCE NOSYNTAXCHECK;
 92
```

Is this an `ESTIMATE` or a `CONTRAST` problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no option DIVISOR for CONTRAST in GLM procedure.

Let's simplify your initial equation.

[image]

Full PROC GLM call:

```
proc glm data=Ex1;
  class technique;
  model time=technique/NOINT SOLUTION E;

  ESTIMATE '(M1+M2+M3)/3-(M3+M4)/2' technique 2 2 -1 -3 0 / divisor=6;
  CONTRAST '(M1+M2+M3)/3=(M3+M4)/2' technique 0.33333 0.333333 -0.166667 -0.5 0 / e ;
run;
```

and output:

[image]

Comment: Also, for the CONTRAST we do not need a divisor and can simplify CONTRAST statement like: CONTRAST '(M1+M2+M3)/3=(M3+M4)/2 simple' technique 2 2 -1 -3 0 / e. It's the same as in the answer.